# Cannot understand Keras ConvLSTM2D - edited

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm looking at the example: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_lstm.py

This RNN is actually predicting the next frame of the movie, so the output should be a movie too (according to the test data fed in). I wonder if there are information lost due to the conv layers with padding.
For example, the underlying Tensorflow is padding bottom right, if there is a big padding: (n stands for numbers)

n n n n 0 0 0
n n n n 0 0 0
n n n n 0 0 0
n n n n 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0

when we do the second conv, the bottom right corner will always be 0, which means the back propagation will never be able to capture anything there. As in this case a movie(a square moves on the whole screen), will it lost the information when the validation label is on the bottom right corner?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Please take a moment to look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the information and sorry for confusion. Basically I was asking if the zero-padding can potentially cause information lost when doing the backpropagation. I asked an AI researcher and strictly speaking - yes,  but it does not affect the overall performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes after asking a Ph.D. doing AI research.